# Kafka log compaction topic gets the key as null

Tags: apache-kafka

I created a log compaction topic in my kafka cluster

I start a console producer like this

```
kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9091 --topic log-compaction-test --property print.key=true --property key.separator=,
```

It listens for new messages. Now if i type `123,abc` , it immediately throws below error.

```
>[2019-09-01 22:12:55,897] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Got error produce response with correlation id 5 on topic-partition log-compaction-test-0, retrying (2 attempts left). Error: CORRUPT_MESSAGE (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[2019-09-01 22:12:56,030] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Got error produce response with correlation id 6 on topic-partition log-compaction-test-0, retrying (1 attempts left). Error: CORRUPT_MESSAGE (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[2019-09-01 22:12:56,134] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Got error produce response with correlation id 7 on topic-partition log-compaction-test-0, retrying (0 attempts left). Error: CORRUPT_MESSAGE (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[2019-09-01 22:12:56,243] ERROR Error when sending message to topic log-compaction-test with key: null, value: 8 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.CorruptRecordException: This message has failed its CRC checksum, exceeds the valid size, has a null key for a compacted topic, or is otherwise corrupt.
```

I also tried this way. no luck.

```
kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 0.0.0.0:9091 --topic log-compaction-test --property print.key=true --property key.separator=,
```

What am I doing wrong? I do send the key. Somehow kafka thinks it is null key.

I use docker containers for zookeeper and kafka brokers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used wrong property `--property print.key=true`. To parse keys you have to pass **parse.key=true**: `--property parse.key=true`